# When I change state in React, my app uses the new state and the old states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a websocket in my React app. It is an app that displays information from coinbase to the screen. I am trying to make it so that when the user changes the currency, my state only pulls in the information that has a product_id with that currency. So what happens is when I first select a currency, it works perfectly fine, I start only getting data with that currency. But when I then change the state of the currency, I starts giving me data with the newly selected currency, but also the ones that were selected before. I'm new to using websockets so maybe I'm missing something there.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "./components/Chart";
import DropDown from "./components/DropDown";



function App() {

  const [bestBid, setBestBid] = useState({price: null, size: null})
  const [bestAsk, setBestAsk] = useState({price: null, size: null})
  const [bidChartData, setBidChartData] = useState()
  const [displayBidChartData, setDisplayBidChartData] = useState([])
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState()
    
 

    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com");

    const apiCall = {
      type: "subscribe",
      product_ids: [
          "ETH-USD",
          "BTC-USD",
          "LTC-USD",
          "BCH-USD"
      ],
      channels: ["level2"]
    };
  
    ws.onopen = (event) => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(apiCall));
    };
  
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
      const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if(json.type === 'l2update'){
        (json.product_id === currency && console.log(json))
      }
     /* if(json.type === 'l2update' && json.product_id === currency){

        const newInfo={price: json.changes[0][1], size: json.changes[0][2]}

        if(json.changes[0][0] === 'buy'){
          setBestBid(newInfo)
        }
   

        //newChartData = {bidPoint: json.bids[0][0], askPoint: json.asks[0][0]}
        
      };*/
    }   
    
    

  function changeCurrency(selection) {
    setCurrency(selection)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <DropDown changeCurrency={changeCurrency} />
      <h3>Best Bid</h3>
      <h6>Bid Price</h6>
      {bestBid.price}
      <h6>Bid Size</h6>
      {bestBid.size}
      <h3>Best Ask</h3>
      <h6>Ask Price</h6>
      {}
      <h6>Ask Size</h6>
      {}
      {currency}
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The main function will run again whenever state changes. You need to move your event listener setup (i.e. code that should only run once) into a useEffect function with an empty dependency array.

Comment: I did have use effect before I posted this, but if I have an empty dependency array, the currency never changes. And if I use the currency state as the dependency, then it just does the same thing of using the current state mixed with old states.

Comment: You have subscribed to four currencies. What do you mean "currency never changes"? Do you mean your Dropdown doesn't work?